# Maximising windows in dual-monitor setup

Tags: multi-monitor

I'm using a dual-dual setup and would like to have youtube videos running maximised on one screen while freeing up the other screen for my IDE. However, as soon as I click the mouse the youtube video will revert back to regular size. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mplayer](http://mplayerhq.hu/) can be given a URL to a video and it will handle the download and display.  To get the real URL to a YouTube video, you can use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) with the user-facing URL (`http://youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX`).

So, knowing that, the way I get fullscreen videos under firefox is by using a helper script that feeds the youtube video to mplayer, via the [launchy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/launchy/) extension that allows sending links to an external application.

To configure launchy, I create a file in `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/chrome/launchy.xml` that will create a contextual menu entry in firefox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configurations xmlns="http://launchy.mozdev.org/configurations">
        <application>
                <label>YouTube to mplayer</label>
                <type>1</type>
                <command>/path/to/bin/yt_mplayer.sh</command>
        </application>
</configurations>
```

Then, this `yt_mplayer.sh` script will handle the rest:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="${@}"
YT_URL=$( youtube-dl -g "${URL}" )
xterm -T "YouTube-MPlayer from Firefox" -e " \
  echo -e Parameters : \"${URL}\n${YT_URL}\"; \
  mplayer -msgcolor -cache 10000 -cache-min 25 \"${YT_URL}\"; \
  read -p '<Return>' foo \
"
```

I like to open a `xterm` to be able to see what's happening with `mplayer` (especially the buffering stage); that could be skipped if you prefer.

This method has not only the advantage of giving you full control over your video, but also saves CPU cycles as `mplayer` has much better performance than browser players.

Comment: Great response -- works a treat! Any idea how you could do the same for non-youtube and/or live streams?

Comment: youtube-dl supports more sites than just youtube (see http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/documentation.html#d4 for a list), but for live streaming, where they often use RTMP, I know of no automated way; often these sites *want* their stuff to be obfuscated.